# How does "+" operator fit into the formal grammar of $\lambda$-calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) I found out that the formal grammar of $\lambda$-calculus is the following:

```
<λexp> ::= <var>
  | λ<var> . <λexp>
  | ( <λexp> <λexp> )
```

Then, a few lines later they say that this is a valid $\lambda$-expression:

$$\lambda x.x^{2}+2$$

How does one matches with the other? Where is the "+" operator in the formal grammar? Where is the integer 2?

Comment: The definition you are giving is of "pure" lambda calculus, but we can add *constants* like $2, +$ and infix and postfix notation for convenience, and call it "applied" lambda calculus.

Comment: How far I can do in making the text after the dot "convenient"? And another question: what's the point of calling the grammar "formal" if we go around the formality?

Comment: As far as you can still formalize it if you want to. You can define the syntactic transformation from e.g. $+(a,b)$ to $a + b$ pretty straightforwardly. The point is to make the system more usable for real-life applications while knowing that you *can* do it formally and prove a lot of interesting things about that formal system that is behind your syntactic sugar if you need to.

Comment: @lemontree: $a+b$ is syntactic sugar for $((+ a) b)$. The transformation is still straightforward.

Comment: Right, $+(a,b)$ is syntactic sugar in itself. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lambda_calculus&oldid=1135426911):

> An abstraction $\lambda x.t$ denotes an anonymous function that takes a single input $x$ and returns $t$. For example, $\lambda x.x^{2}+2$ is an abstraction for the function $f(x)=x^{2}+2$ using the term $x^{2}+2$ for $t$.

It doesn't claim $\lambda x. x^2 + 2$ is a $\lambda$-expression. Rather, it is an example of a general concept of *abstraction*.

In other words, a syntax rule for a lambda expression `λ<var> . <λexp>` is an abstraction, but not every abstraction is a lambda expression.

Similarly, *application* is a syntax rule for a lambda expression but this concept is used for other formalities, such as combinatorial calculus.

Comment: Long story short, without arithmetic operators and numbers, lambda calculus is just a funny collection of good looking letters :)